# Eureka Server with Google app engine (hostname problem)

Tags: google-app-engine, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am building msa using eureka, zuul and with google appengine standard.

The problem is that zuul routing works normally in the local environment, but not in the GAE environment.

If I look at the Eureka page, I can check the registered services.

but The href link in the status column is "192.168.1.1:8080/info"

I know 192.168.1.1 is private ip address... can't access..

The methods i tried

```
#Eureka Standalone Server
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: https://my-eureka-server.appspot.com/eureka/
```

```
#Eureka Client   
eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: https://my-eureka-server.appspot.com/eureka/
```

this result -> http://192.168.1.1:8080/info

```
#Eureka Client  
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: my-eureka-client.appspot.com
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: https://my-eureka-server.appspot.com/eureka/
```

this result -> http://my-eureka-client.appspot.com:8080/info, also can't access

I want to http://my-eureka-client.appspot.com/info

what is hostname???

In local environment, If the euraka hostname is localhost or not specified,

href link is http://localhost:8080/info or http://MY-DESTOP-ID:8080/info
It can access.

Comment: Maybe you can also define port alongside with the hostname in spec?